# Change color of deleted text in changes package

Tags: color, changes

Using the changes package, usually deleted text is colored in blue, how can I change the color to red?

```
\deleted{30 April 2017}
```

Defining an author with

```
\definechangesauthor[color=orange]{.}
```

is not the solution I'm looking for, since it also prints the id next to the change.

Answer (score 3):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{1.,0,0}
\usepackage{changes}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1.}

\begin{document}

\deleted{30 April 2017}

\textcolor{blue}{text}

\end{document}
```

*[No cats were harmed while writing this answer :) ]*

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat! +1

Comment: But what would 1984's Orwell have to say?  Up is down?  Black is white?  "blue" is red?  I am suffering cognitive dissonance.  Is this some form of NewSpeak?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Orwell would surly be proud and keep using tex :)

Comment: Indeed.  You claim no "cats" were harmed by your answer, but can you say the same of "`\catcodes`"?  Now *that* would make Orwell proud!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Oh, nice paronomasia! We should introduce `\dogcodes` as well!

Answer (score 2):

I went to the sty file to see where the change was made, and re-made it otherwise.  The changes all occur inside an invocation of the macro `\definechangesauthor`.  Unfortunately, once called by the package for the default (null) author, it can not be re-invoked by the user [for the null author] with updated keys, without popping an error.

However, one can pull out those components of the `\definechangesauthor` macro where the color actually takes effect and rework just those bits.  In the MWE below, the code inside the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` are where those color quantities are reset.  I have forged it into a macro `\resetchangescolor{<color>}`

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{changes}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\resetchangescolor[1]{%
  \setkeys{Changes@definechangesauthor}{color=#1}%
  \expandafter%
  \let\csname Changes@AuthorColor\endcsname=\Changes@definechangesauthor@color%
  \colorlet{Changes@Color}{\@nameuse{Changes@AuthorColor}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\resetchangescolor{cyan}I eat \added{an} apple.
\resetchangescolor{red}I buy \deleted{a} books.
I buy \replaced{nice}{bad} car.

\listofchanges[style=<list|summary>]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Don't set anything for *added* if you want the default to stay blue, but you can change the *deleted*. Add command to your main file.

```
\setdeletedmarkup{\sout{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```